# Как включить группировку типов данных по папкам в DataGrip?

Tags: datagrip

У меня сейчас вот так:
[image: Описание]

Как сделать так, чтобы когда раскрываешь таблицу, там было рассортированы по папкам `Columns`, `Kyes` и т.д. как тут:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обшерстил настройки и не нашёл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нажать на бургер и выбрать «Group Contents»

[image: DataGrip]

Comment: Попутный вопрос относительно `DataGrip`Почему после сохранения UML диаграммы и повторном открытии все таблицы опять с иерархичном порядке становятся?

Comment: Не знаю, этим не пользовался

Comment: В смысле, у вас не сохраняется layout диаграммы?